# MySQL Adding One to Numeric Column

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code I have the following SQL statement:

$query = "UPDATE users SET num_logins = num_logins+1, last_login='$timeStamp' WHERE id = $id";

I recently implemented the num_logins column for a project administrator so he could see who the frequent users are. It looks like it is working most of the time, however, I've noticed two users who have num_logins = 0 with timestamp values in the last_login field that fall after the date I implemented the change.

The default for the num_logins column is zero, so if they successfully login, and the above query is the only query that updates their last_login field, how is is that num_logins is still zero when their last_login field has been updated (neither field gets updated anywhere else in the code and I am the only db admin)?

ENGINE=InnoDB.

Comment: Mysql won't update just one field and not another. The num_logins incrementation is fine - but how are you generating the timestamp variable? Could that be incorrect? Have you any more code to help diagnose this?

Comment: Have you examined the two that are different? Do they have anything in common with one another that the others (that are working) don't have?

Comment: is there a NULL in the original record perhaps instead of a 0...

Comment: The timestamp is showing up correctly, just num_logins is still zero. There are no NULL values in either column. And I agree. It should update both columns, not just one. And this is the only place in the code where either column gets updated. It is really blowing my mind.

Comment: @A Jolly Geek - Sounds like it's time to add some logging (or turn on your existing logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some scenarios to consider:

1. Are you sure the $id is matching up properly on the update query? Maybe the record isn't being updated.
2. Are you sure all values for the num_logins are not null? Is the column nullable? Default may be 0, but you should check to make sure there aren't any null values. Remember, null + anything is always null.
3. Are you sure the query is actually being executed in your code? Can you add some instrumentation (e.g. logging) to ensure this? Maybe the query isn't being run in all scenarios.

Comment: Thanks dcp for the response. As per #1, yes the id values are matching up. As per #2, there are no NULL values. As per #3, yes the query gets executed because the timestamp field is being set and this is the only place that the last_login field gets set. I'm more inclined to think along the lines of #2, but as far as I can tell, there are no NULL values in the num_logins field.

Comment: @A Jolly Geek - Maybe the timestamp field is being updated by some other query, not the one you suspect. Also, do you have any triggers that could be firing? That would be another possibility (not sure if MySQL has triggers or not to be honest).

Comment: Yes, as octern says, mysql has triggers, but I don't have any on this table. I have enabled logging, which I have not done in years. I'll have to wait to see if another zero value shows. And there are no other places in the code that reference these fields, other than for display. I did a global search of the code base for the two fields, so I know everywhere they get used.